# Items in tab bar not visible when loaded

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a `tabBarController` and two `UINavigationControllers` with `UITableViews` attached to the `tabBarController`. See picture below.

[image: <code>tabBarController</code> setup]

I have subclassed the `tabBarController` so I can pass an array of custom objects between the two tables by reference. Whenever I load the tabs, however, the items are not appearing. They are still able to be selected but you just can't see them. The below picture shows the `tabBar` with none of the `items` showing

[image: <code>tabBar</code> with <code>items</code> not visible]

I have a feeling it is because I am instantiating the `viewControllers` and the `UINavigationController` is not loading. I am just not sure how to go about having the `UINavigationController` to load first.

**The code I am using is below:**

```
var table1 : AllPlacesViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AllPlaces") as AllPlacesViewController

var table2:AttendingPlacesTableViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AttendingPlaces") as AttendingPlacesTableViewController

table1.delegate = self
table2.delegate = self

var navController1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: table1)
var navController2 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: table2)

self.viewControllers = [navController1, navController2]
```

The reason I set them up like this is because I want to share data between the `viewControllers` by reference.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use the "Editor|Embed In" option to embed the Navigation Controllers in the Tabbar? That is very important! Tabbars with Navigation Controllers were a problem in older versions but this XCode function helps to solve issues like this I think.

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding everything you've set up in the storyboard by setting a different set of view controllers in your code. No need to create any of those objects in code as they'll be instantiated by the storyboard.

**EDIT:**

<s>Instead, set unique identifiers for each of the `Segues` and in your custom tab bar controller, override the 'prepareForSegue' method</s>

```
// MARK: - Segue handling

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == kSegue_YourSegueIdentifier {
        if let viewController : YourCustomVC = segue.destinationViewController as? YourCustomVC {
            viewController.delegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

Tweak the method to check all relevant segue identifiers or, in case of UINavigationControllers, fetch it's root view controller for setting delegate etc.

I did not pay enough attention to the storyboard in your image. Tab bar view controller's tabs and the navigation controller's root view controller segues will not have segue identifiers.

You can directly access them by iterating through your tab bar controller's `viewControllers` array in `viewDidLoad`.

EDIT 2:

You can iterate through your view controllers easily

```
    for viewController in self.tabBarController!.viewControllers! {
        if let navigationController = viewController as? UINavigationController {
            if let yourCustomVC = navigationController as? YourCustomVCClass {
                yourCustomVC.delegate = self
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am trying to implement this method but the segue to the `navigationController` is a relationship segue and I can't set an identifier on it. Would I need to create a manual segue for this to work? Also, will the method you put replace all of the code I currently have?

Comment: I am fairly new to swift so have been searching how to iterate through the `viewControllers` array. I am having trouble finding out how to do this in swift. What would the best way to go about iterating through the `viewContollers` be?

Answer (score 0):

Creating your navigationControllers in code you are ignoring a Storyboard UINavigationControllers that have UITabBarItem created for you automatically by UITabBarController, thats why you don't see nothing.
You also need create an UITabBarItem for each custom navigationControllers